# Style JSON with HTML in Angular App

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am injecting text into my Angular app with JSON objects. There is a "bio" section which requires HTML styling such as `<br />` that way the text is not one chunk of unreadable text. I have tried `trustAsHtml` but it did not work for me. A working example would be best as I have read through Angular documentation and cannot get anyhting to work for me.

Help is greatly appreciated!

**HTML w/ Angular JS**

```
<div class="bio">
    {{exhibits[whichItem].bio}}
</div>
```

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "name":"Name goes here",
    "bio":"First long block of text goes here then it needs a break <br /> and the second long block of text is here."
  }
]
```

Comment: How did it not work?  Was there a console error from angular or did it not display?  Can you give an example of how you are using the trustAsHtml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add 'ngSanitize' module as dependency 
also you have to include corresponding script :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

then use `ng-bind-html`

```
<div class="bio" ng-bind-html="exhibits[whichItem].bio">

</div>
```

if you don't use `ngSanitize` module , it will give you error for `ng-bind-html`

You can refer [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: This did it! At first I couldn't get it to work, then I remembered I had to call it in angular.module. You really helped me out big time, and I am really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
<div class="bio"ng-bind-html=exhibits[whichItem].bio>

</div>
```

Will probably do the trick.